# Component identification - do you know what are the values of these components?

Tags: pcb, components, identification

I am trying to identify the capacitance and resistance of two components that are soldered on a PCB.

The capacitor below should be 10 nF according to the datasheet. But its code is not 103. What's the value of this capacitor?

[image]

The resistor below should be 4k7 Ohms according to the datasheet. Then the band colors should be yellow, violet, red, and tolerance. But the third band is black instead of red. Then it is 47 Ohms instead of 4k7. Am I right?

[image]

Comment: @winny Capacitor Code 103 = 10 x 1000 (pF / pico Farad) = 10.000pF (pico Farad) where 10.000 pF = 10 nF (nano Farad) = 0.01 uF (micro Farad)

Comment: Sorry. I must have slipped there. I’ll delete my old comment to clear up any future confusion. 103 = 10E^3 pF = 10 nF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cap is 33nF (333 -> **33** x 10^**3** = 33000pF)

The resistor is 4k7. It's an odd-looking 5-band, so the 4 resistance bands are:
4701 (**470** x 10^**1** = 4700).
The 5th band looks brown-ish, so probably 1% tolerance.

Comment: +1 The resistor is 4.70K +/-1% (brown) the capacitor is 33nF +/-10% (K) 50V X7R (as marked).